# Oracle SQL: return results on one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I make the following results appear on one row?

Currently the CASE_COMPONENT_PART, CASE_DESCRIPTION and CASE_PROD are on a different row to the TRAY_COMPONENT_PART, TRAY_DESCRIPTION and TRAY_PROD.

Can the results all appear on the same row?

```
select li.cunr, oc.name cust_name, li.catnr fp_catnr, li.av_part_no fp_part_no, 
trim(li.artist||' '||li.title) fp_description,
(case when substr(li1.prodtyp,1,2) = 'JC' then 
(case 
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null 
            then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null and 
        (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps3.component_part else '' end)
    else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end)
end) 
else '' end) case_component_part,
(case when substr(li1.prodtyp,1,2) = 'JC' then
(case 
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null 
            then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd2.description else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end) is null and 
        (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd2.description else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd3.description else '' end)
    else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end)
end) 
else '' end) case_description,
(case when substr(li1.prodtyp,1,2) = 'JC' then substr(li1.prodtyp,1,2) else '' end) case_prod,
(case when substr(li2.prodtyp,1,2) = 'TR' then 
(case 
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null 
            then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null and 
        (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps3.component_part else '' end)
    else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end)
end) 
else '' end) tray_component_part,
(case when substr(li2.prodtyp,1,2) = 'TR' then 
(case 
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null 
            then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd2.description else '' end)
    when
        (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end) is null and  
        (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd1.description else '' end) is null and 
        (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd2.description else '' end) is null
            then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd3.description else '' end)
    else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then pd.description else '' end)
end) 
else '' end) tray_description,
(case when substr(li2.prodtyp,1,2) = 'TR' then substr(li2.prodtyp,1,2) else '' end)  tray_prod
from leos_item li, oes_customer oc, product_structure ps, part_description pd, 
product_structure ps1, part_description pd1, product_structure ps2, part_description pd2,
product_structure ps3, part_description pd3,
leos_item li1, leos_item li2 
where li.cugrp = 'VDC'
and li.item_type = 'FP' 
and li.cunr = oc.cunr
and li.av_part_no = ps.parent_part (+)
and ps.component_part = pd.part_no (+)
and ps.component_part = ps1.parent_part (+)
and ps1.component_part = pd1.part_no (+)
and ps1.component_part = ps2.parent_part (+)
and ps2.component_part = pd2.part_no (+)
and ps2.component_part = ps3.parent_part (+)
and ps3.component_part = pd3.part_no (+)
and (case 
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null 
                then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end)
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
            (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null
                then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end)
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
            (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null and 
            (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end) is null
                then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps3.component_part else '' end)
        else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end)
    end) = li1.av_part_no
and (case 
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null 
                then (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end)
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
            (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null
                then (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end)
        when
            (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end) is null and  
            (case when substr(pd1.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps1.component_part else '' end) is null and 
            (case when substr(pd2.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps2.component_part else '' end) is null
                then (case when substr(pd3.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps3.component_part else '' end)
        else (case when substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','TR') then ps.component_part else '' end)
    end) = li2.av_part_no
and li.catnr = 'GTSTCD100'
```

Thanks, SMORF

Answer (score 0):

1.separate all Difference Column

2.make sub query with all Difference column then convert to Pivot

3.join with main query again

```
SELECT CASE_COMPONENT_PART
     , CASE_DESCRIPTION
     ,CASE_PROD

FROM table_a

LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT id [PK_for_join_first_query]
         ,TRAY_COMPONENT_PART
         ,TRAY_DESCRIPTION,TRAY_PROD

    FROM table_b -- Pivot this Query
)
```